# Is it acceptable to omit 的 before a noun in degree complement, when the verb follows the noun?

Tags: grammar

In the example sentence (according to [Chinese grammar wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Degree_complement)):

> 你的菜做得很好。
>
> 你的字写得很漂亮。
>
> 你的中文说得很好。

In these cases, all use 的 before a noun, once it moves before the verb. The original sentence does not use 的 to modify the noun (e.g. 你做菜做得很好。).

But I feel I have also seen such sentences without 的 modification, for example:

> 你菜做得很好。
>
> 你字写得很漂亮。
>
> 你中文说得很好。

Or the sentence that made me determined to open this question:

> 凭着他的才能和经验，他在云南**事情**办得很顺利。

Maybe syllables are also taken in consideration here. 你中文说得很好 sounds more natural than the others, as those nouns are just one character.

So is it acceptable or not to omit 的 here? Or is it grammatically wrong but used commonly?

Comment: Agree with @TangHo's answer. Generally speaking, 你菜做得很好 is a comment about 你 (subject), while 你的菜做得很好 is a comment about 你的菜 (subject).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot omit the possessive 的 in 你的菜, 你的字, 你的中文, if your comments are about 'your cooking', 'your writing' or 'your Chinese'

However, you can remove (not omit) '的' to change the topic from '你的~ (your~)' to '你 (you)'

> [你的菜 (topic)] [做得很好(comment)] - "your cooking is cooked very well"
>
> [你的字 (topic)] [写得很漂亮 (comment)] " your writing is written very beautifully"
>
> [你的中文 (topic)] [说得很好 (comment)] "Your Chinese is spoken very well"
>
> *'你的菜', '你的字' and '你的中文' are the topics*

~

> [你 (topic)] [菜做得很好 (comment)] - "you cook very well"
>
> [你 (topic)] [字写得很漂亮 (comment)] - "you write very beautifully"
>
> [你 (topic)] [中文说得很好 (comment)] - "you speak Chinese very well"
>
> *'你' is the topics*

~

> '你做得很好', '你写得很漂亮' and '你说得很好' are basic [subject + verb]  phrases

Comment: Thanks but in English, I feel they are the same...

Comment: OK, than do continue feeling they are the same, but understand that the grammar is not.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nuance.

你菜做得很好 means ***generally your cooking is good***.

Well, 你的菜做得很好,  depending on contexts, could mean either ***generally your cooking is good*** or ***the speaker refers to those dishes cooked by you are good***.

But in practice, there really isn't any difference and you can use them interchangeably.

This reminds me a similar omission in English: *I go see your dog* vs *I go to see your dog*.